# Какой ПК требуется для работы с моделью YOlOv8 и видеопотоком "rtsp:..."&!

Tags: deep-learning

Стоит задача использовать модель YOLOv8 на прямой трансляции. Использую пока ПК с такими характеристиками: Оперативная память -  15 Гиг., Видеокарта - Intel UHD 630  и процессор - Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8350k CPU 4.00GHz.
Модель работает нормально, если ставить задержку в 0.3 секунды. Этот ПК не успевает обрабатывать количество поступающих кадров из видеопотока. Как понимаю - проблема в видеокарте.
какие характеристики подойдут для беспрерывной работы модели с прямой трансляцией?